# PHP Check Text in Variable after N text

Tags: php

How to check value variable that contains text after N text.

Example :

```
$a = "I need you";
```

then PHP do something :

```
<?php
check if in $a after text "you" there is a text, then echo found text after "You"
?>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: So if I interpret your pseudo code right, you just want to check if there is text after a certain word in a string?! If yes have you tried something ?

Comment: Yes correct, nope, I just got the logic but confused when try to code it in PHP

Comment: Little hint: [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and then check if the next position in the string isset, maybe you will be able to solve this yourself :D!

Comment: @Rizier123 I never use any of these functions but I'm actually wondering if `strpos()` combined with `substr` would work? Because `strpos` doesn't count spaces and I dont know about `substr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$a = "I need you";
$search = "need";
$substring = substr($a, strpos($a,$search)+strlen($search));
echo $substring;
```

echoes **" you"**

Comment: I just tested: `strpos` together  with `substr` and I've noticed that `strpos()` doesn't count spaces and `substr` does. So in some cases this will actually not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode()`

```
$exploded = explode('you', $a);
if(!empty(end($exploded))){
  echo "Found text after you";
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the text that's after "you" instead of literally: Found text after you. I can be wrong though

Comment: But this assumes that the word is in the string otherwise it will return true even if the word isn't in the string

Comment: Tried and got an error : Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in...

Comment: @Loko Got it, misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Rizier123 I'm aware, just offering some kind of method he can use.

Comment: @HiDayurieDave Sorry for that forgot to mention you'll need PHP 5.5 or higher.